# How to add a text into Material UI speed dial button?

Tags: button, material-ui, frontend, customization, speed-dial

How to change the material ui speeddial button, apparently it uses the Fab default and all you can do is to change the Icon, but I need to add a text as well, for example:

```
<Fab variant="extended">
    <NavigationIcon />
    Actions
</Fab>
```

Answer (score 3):

Sorry that this is late, but I recently ran into this problem and found the solution:

`SpeedDial` comes with `FabProps` prop to enable you to modify the Fab (Fab docs: https://mui.com/material-ui/api/fab/).
So firstly you should modify the `Fab` to use `variant="extended"`. Then to add your text, use the `icon` prop from `SpeedDialIcon`.

So your component should look something like this:

```
<SpeedDial
  FabProps={{ variant: "extended" }}
  icon={
    <SpeedDialIcon
      icon={
        <Box sx={{ display: "flex" }}>
          <YourIcon />
          <Typography> {/* Your text */} </Typography>
        </Box>
    />
  }
/>
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Use `SpeedDialAction` for this purpose

```js
    <SpeedDialAction
       key={action.name}
       icon={action.icon} // here goes your icon
       tooltipTitle={action.name} // here goes your text
       tooltipOpen
       onClick={handleClose}
    />
```

On hover you will see
[image]

- [Documentation](https://material-ui.com/components/speed-dial/) for it
- [Live example](https://codesandbox.io/s/qogpp?file=/demo.js)

2. Or use [floating action button](https://v4.mui.com/components/floating-action-button/) for your purpose

```js
    <Fab
        aria-label={fab.label}
        className={fab.className}
        color={fab.color}
    >
        {fab.icon}
    </Fab>
```

[image]

- [Documentation](https://v4.mui.com/components/floating-action-button/) for it
- [Live example](https://codesandbox.io/s/whrmz)

---

Please, let me know if it works for you or not )

Comment: That's not what he is looking for, seems like he want to have some primary text before opening the dial actions, I'm trying to do the same right now